# Unsubscribing from an observable when another observable is unsubscribed

Tags: javascript, rxjs, ngrx, rxjs6

Suppose I have a list of items that is queried from an API depending on a parameter that can be changed in the UI. When changing the value of this parameter, I dispatch an action:

```
this.store$.dispatch(new ChangeParameterAction(newParameterValue));
```

Now, on the receiving end, I want to trigger a new API call on every parameter change. I do this by subscribing to the store and then switching to the API observable. Then, I dispatch the result back into the store:

```
/** Statement 1 **/
this.store$.select(selectParameter).pipe(
    switchMap(parameter => this.doApiCall$(parameter))
).subscribe(apiResult => {
    this.store$.dispatch(new ResultGotAction(apiResult))
});
```

My UI is receiving the items by subscribing to

```
/** Statement 2 **/
this.store$.select(selectResults);
```

Now my question is: How can I join these two statements together so that we only have the subscription for Statement 1 for as long as the UI showing the results is active (and not destroyed)? I will always subscribe to the result of Statement 2, so Statement 1 will never be unsubscribed.

I've tried merging both observables and ignoring the elements for Statement 1, then subscribing tothe merged observables. But this looks like a very unreadable way for doing such a basic task. I think there must be a better way, but I can't find one. Hope you can help!

Comment: What determines `as long as my UI is actually interested in the results` ?

Comment: In Angular I'd subscribe with `| async`. If the view is destroyed, it unsubscribes automatically. Rephrased the question.

Comment: So what you're looking for is: how to unsubscribe from `Stmt1` when `Stmt2` unsubscribes, right?

Comment: yes, exactly :)

Comment: Then, if `Stmt2` unsubscribes when the comp is destroyed and `Stmt1` unsubscribes when `Stmt2` does, wouldn't be easier to add a `takeUntil(unsubscribe)` to both? `unsubscribe = new Subject()`, emits on `ngOnDestroy`

Comment: yeah I guess I can't really have a single subject there, because these statements are part of a singleton service that is used by multiple components instances.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell exactly if this would run correctly, but I would go with moving the dispatch of `ResultGotAction` to a `tap` operator and then switching to `this.store$.select(selectResults)`

For example:

```js
this.store$.select(selectParameter).pipe(
  switchMap(parameter => this.doApiCall$(parameter)),
  tap(apiResult => this.store$.dispatch(new ResultGotAction(apiResult))),
  switchMapTo(this.store$.select(selectResults))
);
```

Comment: Yeah this would run, but I'd resubscribe to the store after every change. That wouldn't hurt in this case, but if we think of a more general solution to this, the unsubscribing could be unwanted. (Say, you had a Firebase Store instead and it would always unsubscribe and subscribe again after an Update - there would probably be unwanted network traffic).